# How can I find the cause of my CentOS 6.8 server crashing (suffering kernel panic) every two days?

Tags: centos, crash, kernel-panic

My server is crashing every two days around early afternoon.  I've tried overloading the server with CPU intensive programs but that does not cause it to crash so I believe it to be a certain program or configuration.   being run that is causing it.  I've downloaded crash and tried doing some simple commands on it but I'm not sure what it is outputting.

```
[root@resh boot]# crash /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64/vmlinux /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2016-08-02-09\:12\:20/vmcore
KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64/vmlinux
DUMPFILE: /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2016-08-02-09:12:20/vmcore  [PARTIAL DUMP]
CPUS: 32
DATE: Tue Aug  2 09:09:29 2016
UPTIME: 12:47:24
LOAD AVERAGE: 4.78, 4.66, 4.55
TASKS: 998
NODENAME: resh.cluster.org
RELEASE: 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64
VERSION: #1 SMP Tue May 31 21:57:07 UTC 2016
MACHINE: x86_64  (2294 Mhz)
MEMORY: 31.8 GB
PANIC: "BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 
0000000000000002"
PID: 42993
COMMAND: "kslowd002"
TASK: ffff88040d88d520  [THREAD_INFO: ffff880100000000]
CPU: 7
STATE: TASK_RUNNING (PANIC)

crash> bt
PID: 42993  TASK: ffff88040d88d520  CPU: 7   COMMAND: "kslowd002"
#0 [ffff8801000039c0] machine_kexec at ffffffff8103fdcb
#1 [ffff880100003a20] crash_kexec at ffffffff810d1fe2
#2 [ffff880100003af0] oops_end at ffffffff8154bd00
#3 [ffff880100003b20] no_context at ffffffff810518cb
#4 [ffff880100003b70] __bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff81051b55
#5 [ffff880100003bc0] bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff81051c23
#6 [ffff880100003bd0] __do_page_fault at ffffffff8105231c
#7 [ffff880100003cf0] do_page_fault at ffffffff8154dc8e
#8 [ffff880100003d20] page_fault at ffffffff8154af95
[exception RIP: unknown or invalid address]
RIP: 0000000000000002  RSP: ffff880100003dd8  RFLAGS: 00010202
RAX: ffffffffa0465a80  RBX: ffff8801bc7da200  RCX: ffff8801bc7da2a8
RDX: 0000000000000002  RSI: 00000000ffffffff  RDI: ffff8801bc7da200
RBP: ffff880100003e20   R8: ffffffff81ad12d8   R9: fe2582cc8764a601
R10: 0000000000000001  R11: 0000000000000000  R12: 0000000000000000
R13: ffff8801bc7da248  R14: ffff8801bc7da290  R15: 00000000ffffffff
ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
#9 [ffff880100003dd8] fscache_object_slow_work_execute at ffffffffa0460e9f [fscache]
#10 [ffff880100003e28] slow_work_execute at ffffffff81121363
#11 [ffff880100003e68] slow_work_thread at ffffffff81121645
#12 [ffff880100003ee8] kthread at ffffffff810a662e
#13 [ffff880100003f48] kernel_thread at ffffffff8100c28a
```

Since it seemed to be happening every two days, I've tried looking at the cron jobs but there are no cron jobs that match a schedule of every two days.  I've also tried updating the kernel but that has not helped at all either.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1236723

Comment: Run a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I realize this post is ancient history now, but I just had this same exact error happen tonight.  Notice the stack entry

```
#9 [ffff880100003dd8] fscache_object_slow_work_execute at ffffffffa0460e9f [fscache]
```

It's just a hunch, but we've had problems with post-2.6.32-642 kernels when *cachefilesd* has been running.  We turned it off on our RHEL 6.x systems with these post-*Dirty COW* kernels.

Update: see [this Red Hat Solutions page](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2439131) for more info about the problem.

Is *cachefilesd* running on this system?  If so, give it a try, turn it off and disable it.

Comment: Yes!  We have been turning off cachefilesd on all our hosts...  We too noticed this process running away and causing issues over time.